# Java Date duration validation

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I will have 2 dates i.e. start date and end date. i have to calculate the duration between both the dates and then that duration should be checked for all below 3 conditions -

1. If the duration is Equal to(1 year +- 5 days), then print "Hello".
2. If the duration is Smaller than (1 year -5 days), then print "Hi".
3. If the duration is Greater than (1 year + 5 days), then print "Hi".

Please help me and let me know if any more information is required.

I prefered to use joda time api. duration calculation is quite easy. I have problem to put the condition to validate with all above said 3 condition. whatever if condition i put in my program is not proper it seems.

```java
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;

class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        Period p1 = new Period(d1, d2);
        if (p1.getYears()==1 && p1.getMonths()==0 &&
                (p1.getDays()<5||p1.getDays()>5)) {
            System.out.println("Hello");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Hi");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: last two conditions seems funny.

Comment: what so funny is there in that. if duration is below and above to the said period then some logic should be performed else some other logic should be performed.

Comment: dude, i have updated the question with program. you can suggest some solution based on that approach if possible. I appriciate your immediate response. thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

User the following class, that has a `daysBetween` method which you can use to calculate the number of days.

```
 public class DateDifference {
 public static void main(String args[]){
 DateDifference difference = new DateDifference();
 }
 DateDifference() {
 Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar();
 Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();

 cal1.set(2008, 8, 1); 
 cal2.set(2008, 9, 31);
 System.out.println("Days= "+daysBetween(cal1.getTime(),cal2.getTime()));
 }
 public int daysBetween(Date d1, Date d2){
 return (int)( (d2.getTime() - d1.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
 }
 }
```

I don't think you will need help anymore unless you do not know how many days are there in a year and you do not no how to use `if...else` blocks in java.

Comment: If you just check that there are for example less than 360 or more than 370 days between two dates, you are not taking leap years into account. The length of a period like "1 year + 5 days" depends on whether it's a leap year or not.

Answer (score 0):

You have to watch out that the duration of 1 year is not always fixed, because some years have 365 days and other days have 366 days. So you cannot simply count the number of days between the dates without taking leap years into account; that would not always lead to correct results.

I'd do it like this:

```
DateTime start = d1.plusYears(1).minusDays(5);
DateTime end = d1.plusYears(1).plusDays(5);

if (d2.isBefore(start)) {
    System.out.println("Difference between d1 and d2 is less than 1 year - 5 days");
} else if (d2.isAfter(end)) {
    System.out.println("Difference between d1 and d2 is more than 1 year + 5 days");
} else {
    System.out.println("Difference is more than or equal to 1 year + 5 days " +
                       "and less than or equal to 1 year - 5 days");
}
```

Comment: updating question section with my final program.

Answer (score 0):

I prefered to use joda time api. duration calculation is quite easy. I have problem to put the condition to validate with all above said 3 condition. whatever if condition i put in my program is not proper it seems.

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Period;

class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    Period p1 = new Period(d1, d2);
     if(p1.getYears()==1 && p1.getMonths()==0 &&
     (p1.getDays()<5||p1.getDays()>5)){
    System.out.println("Hello");
     }else{
    System.out.println("Hi");
               }

}
```

}

Here is my program which works as my expectations -

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;

class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DateTime d1 = new DateTime(2011, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime d2 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    DateTime start=d1.plusYears(1).minusDays(5);
    DateTime end=d1.plusYears(1).plusDays(5);
    if(d2.isBefore(start)||d2.isAfter(end)){
        System.out.println("HI");
    }else{
        System.out.println("HELLO");
    }

}
```

}